How to deploy a react app using mono repo on IIs
I have created a react app using Monorepo. When I create build it created two folder one app and send libs. Inside app folder there is main project folder and its name is my-project.
I want to deploy this to IIS. but after deploying it did not find css etc. In IIS I set physical path up to apps/my-project. Are any steps required on IIS?
I also tried using reroute module in IIS.
